# SonarLint alerting for a java:S1206 issue but hashCode and equals are implemented

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarlint

I have a small Java project on Eclipse which I like to check code smells using SonarLint, but today I've got this strange `java:S1206` issue which says `"equals(Object obj)" and "hashCode()" should be overridden in pairs`.
This issue is being reported on a long-time model object which correctly overrides `equals` and `hashCode` methods.

[image: Java class overriding both "hashCode" and "equals".]

I've already tried re-run SonarLint a few times, but the results are the same. Last modification I've done is update some dependencies version and imports.

I'm using Eclipse 2019-12 (4.14.0) Build id: 20191212-1212 and SonarLint for Eclipse version 5.0.0.15138. Eclipse is running using JDK 1.8.0_231.

Project code can be found on my [ISS-Tracker GitHub repository](https://github.com/MarceloLeite2604/iss-tracker).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the problem is regarding the Java virtual machine (JVM) version I was using to execute Eclipse. I modified `eclipse.ini` file to execute Eclipse using JVM 11 and no issues were reported by SonarLint. To be sure of it, I've removed the configuration, restarted Eclipse, re-executed SonarLint report and the java:S1206 issue reappeared.

For those who are facing the same problem (or similar, perhaps):

1. Download a Java Virtual Machine 11;
2. Install the JVM on your machine and annotate (copy) the installation directory (e. g. `/opt/openjdk/jdk-11.0.2`);
3. Open `$ECLIPSE_HOME/eclipse.ini` file on a text editor;
4. Add the following lines replacing `<JAVA_HOME>` by your annotated installation directory;

```
-vm
<JAVA_HOME>/bin
```

`eclipse.ini` file should be looking like this:

[image: eclipse.ini file after JVM configuration lines have been added]

6. Restart Eclipse.
7. Run SonarLint report again by right-clicking on project folder, menu `SonarLint`, item `Analyze`.